# windows/office licenses after image capture

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, license, windows-activation, software-activation

I am trying to create non sysprepped recovery images for individual laptops.

Will the Windows and Office activation be retained after reapplying the image? The purpose of it is to spend as little time and effort restoring them to original state without having to keep track of individual licenses.

Comment: Why are you not preparing the system images?  You will have to change the Windows license on each laptop and reinstall Office ( because I know of no other way to change the Office key ).  You will have to activate each copy if the software detects a change.

Comment: the purpose of it is to have one recovery disc for 1 device. These will be going out to clients far away from me. So what I am trying to achieve is to have a non sysprepped image with all the licenses already activated that the user can just restore without having to request license information for any products. The device will always be the same so no licensing laws are broken.

Comment: If the hardware just not change then an image created with the software activated won't need to be activated.   If these laptops have an internet connection then it won't matter, the software will activate automatically, without a problem if its required.